# Orientation of 3 points in 2d plane

Tags: computational-geometry

Currently I am taking a computational geometry course and I have learnt that:

*Orientation is formally defined as the sign of the determinant of the
points given in homoge- neous coordinates. For example, in the plane,
we have Orient(p,q,r) = determinant of the matrix:*

```
1 ax ay

1 bx by

1 cx cy
```

What is the mathematical explanation for this formula?

I have expand the determinant and come up with this:

```
det(P) = (bx - ax)(cy - ay) - (cx - ax)(by - ay)
```

I also know an additional information which may lead to something useful, if the crossproduct *(b-a)x(c-a)* results in the +z direction then the rotation is positive. However, I am not able to derive anything from there. What should be my next step?

Thanks

Comment: Does the determinant written in that form remind you of anything?

Comment: Signed area of the triangle pqr? I dont know the theory.

Comment: It's exactly the crossproduct $(b-a) \times (c-a)$.